How to force Angular Animations to pick the latest value?
I have a component that changes size every now and then. When it gets destroyed, I need its current height for the :leave animation. The animation is bound to the component by @HostBinding().
ngOnDestroy() runs before the :leave animation starts, so that seems to be a good place to measure the current height:
private elementRef = inject(ElementRef);

@HostBinding(`@out`) out = {
  value: false,
  params: { height: 20 }, // just a random value
};

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  const height = this.elementRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  console.log(`Height in ngOnDestroy: `, height);
  this.out = {
    value: true,
    params: { height: height },
  };
}

The animation runs, so it must have got the value: true part in time. If I later (before destroying the component) change the params: {height: someNewValue} to anything, that works. But when I do it in ngOnDestroy(), the new height param doesn't get applied. Seems like Angular Animations has a slight delay with params (I assume it makes a RegExp search for the {{height}} part in the trigger and maybe some other stuff, which takes time). Is there a way to force Angular to use the newest params value? Some way to force it to wait?
I made a Stackblitz to show what I mean. This is not what I want to do for real, but it shows the principe of the problem.

can you tell me what is the graphical result you want to have?

The animation is identical to the one in Stackblitz, except that it's faster (150ms). It should just become flat and then disappear. The stuff happening around is more complicated, but in short it's a component that smoothly adjusts itself to the size of it's contents.

so if I understand well you want the square to enlarge when clicking add then diminish whe clicking remove and you want to the transition to leave at the current height of the square? tell me if I'm wrong?

The square is just a made up example, since I don't want to put large amounts of proprietary code on SO. It just shows the principle of the problem. Namely, the square should smoothly flatten when getting removed. But it doesn't, it jumps to the height: 70, it doesn't pick the value that I've set in ngOnDestroy(), even though it runs before the animation starts.
